# Calling WCF Request with SOAPUI

Tags: .net, wcf, soapui

I want to call a **WCF** Request using the **SOAPUI** Open Source variant.

I am running the WCF service locally and I have gotten the "required" info/data from tracing (system.diagnostics) to compose the request: the raw xml-envelope and the endpoint.

I am trying it out in SOAPUI:

- Using POST-method
- NO wsdl-file, i.e. I am pasting the raw xml-envelope I got from the svclog in the **Request Message Tab**.
- Endpoint is a Uri from the svclog: **net.tcp://127.0.0.1:5333/MyGenericWcfMethod**

When using this endpoint I get the following exception in SOAPUI's errorlog:

An error occurred [com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.RequestTransportRegistry$**MissingTransportException**: Missing transport for protocol [net.tcp]]

So I tried instead using the endpoint: **http://127.0.0.1:5333/MyGenericWcfMethod**

This does not work either, I do not get any connection.

I have not bothered to validate the contents of the envelope, as I do not get that far because of the exceptions.

So, my questions are:

- Is it possible to use tcp-endpoints at all in SOAPUI?
- Do the enpoints look correct? I entered the "whole" endpoint in the **Endpoint** field, i.e. nothing in **Resource** field or the **Parameters** field.

Thanks, Regards

Comment: What Binding you are using is it TCP or HTTP?

Comment: TCP. This binding is created at the startup of the WCF service. The address 127.0.0.1 and port 5333 are read from a .config file (would be different in a production scenario of course).

Comment: Are you calling soap service or a rest?because you mentioned no wsdl. And also talking about parameters. If it is a soap service thew must be a wsdl. Get that wsdl to make it testing easy. Otherwise, try to use http request. But that may be not just easy add you need to have information about what headers you need to send along with request.

Comment: It is not a rest-API. WCF services are, correct me if I am wrong, inherently based on SOAP.

Comment: After some googling, it seems SOAPUI does not support NetTcpBinding. I am thinking about writing a test client app, using WebClient or TcpClient and figure out what the headers should look like.

Comment: To avoid confusion, this thread can be closed, as I have decided to take a different approach, meaning not using SOAPUI.